# Yii2 relationship hasOne

Tags: yii2, yii2-model, yii2-active-records

I have 2 simple models:

```
class Page extends ActiveRecord {

    public static function tableName() {
        return 'page';
    }

    public function getPageType() {
        return $this->hasOne(PageType::className(), ['id', 'page_type_id']);
    }
}

class PageType extends ActiveRecord {

    public static function tableName() {
        return 'page_type';
    }

    public function getPages() {
        return $this->hasMany(Page::className(), ['page_type_id', 'id']);
    }

}
```

I am trying to get a list of pages and filter them by `page_type_id`, so i am doing:

```
Page::find()
     ->joinWith('pageType')
     ->where(['page.service_id' => $this->serviceId, 'page.active' => 1])
     ->all();
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'page_type.0' in 'on clause'
The SQL being executed was: SELECT `page`.* FROM `page` 
LEFT JOIN `page_type` 
   ON 
     `page`.`id` = `page_type`.`0` 
      AND 
     `page`.`page_type_id` = `page_type`.`1` 
WHERE 
      (`page`.`service_id`=1) AND (`page`.`active`=1)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the column names in the relation as `name=>value` pairs, not comma-separated list.

```
return $this->hasOne(PageType::className(), ['id', 'page_type_id']);
```

and

```
return $this->hasMany(Page::className(), ['page_type_id', 'id']);
```

Change your relations and your classes code look like following

```
class Page extends ActiveRecord {

    public static function tableName() {
        return 'page';
    }

    public function getPageType() {
        return $this->hasOne(PageType::className(), ['id'=> 'page_type_id']);
    }
}

class PageType extends ActiveRecord {

    public static function tableName() {
        return 'page_type';
    }

    public function getPages() {
        return $this->hasMany(Page::className(), ['page_type_id'=>'id']);
    }

}
```

Comment: You are right, it was be the 12 hours straight I was working on this yesterday :D, thanks!